# Open XML SDK for office library available in JavaScript?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, openxml-sdk, word-web-addins

I need to update the footer part of a Word document in MAC (Which is not active, i.e. closed) by inserting Content Control and modifying it.
I have explored the office Add-in. But I don't think I can use it to edit a Word document, which is not active (in closed state).

I have successfully utilised the NuGet package:DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Framework( https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Framework))  in C# in Visual Studio for MAC and is able to build the solution.

But I want to integrate this functionality with my existing Javascript code. Is there any reliable npm package which I can use to edit a Word document?
Or is there any way, I can integrate the C# solution with Javascript?

I have explored the office Add-in. But I don't think I can use it to edit a Word document, which is not active (in closed state).

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right. There is no way to edit a document on the disk from your Office web add-in which can be run only for the opened document in MS Word. For security reasons Office web add-ins don't have access to the hard drive and can be run in a sandbox (like any other web application).

Also there is no way to call external applications like the one with a Nuget package from Office web add-ins.

You suggest a feature to the Office team to get the required functionality implemented at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: Can I use Open XML SDK for Office from Node.js ?

Comment: Yes, you can use any NodeJS packages that deal with open XML documents.

Comment: Any reliable npm package available for open-XML SDk? Similar to Nuget package DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Framework (https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Framework). 
Any package provided/recommended by Microsoft?

Comment: There is no recommended package for `NodeJS`. It is up to you how to handle open XML documents from JavaScript. You can even edit the files on your own. Open XML documents are just zip archives.